# Execute function in elements by class not running

Tags: jquery, class, onclick

I can't run this code, Jquery is okay, I done it inside $(document) because of some advice read here in the site, that I forgot the link. The problem is that it does not run.. Sorry if it's fool question, I am not a front-end programmer. -Please ignore on onclick="adicionaItemNoMenu();return false;" inside button

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {});
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.botaoMenu').click(function() {
                    alert("Oi");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="1" class="botaoMenu">Menu 1</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Whole Code with not mainly codes:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.botaoMenu').click(function() {
        // $(this.id).html($(this.id).html+'<ul><li><input type="submit" value="Novo Item"></li></ul>');
        alert("Oi");
        });
});


var id=1;
var menuPrincipal = [];

function itemMenu(idItem,descricao) {
    this.idItem=idItem;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.posicao = menuPrincipal.length+1;
    this.link = "";
    this.itensMenuInterno=[];
}


function adicionaBotao()
{           
    //$("#menu").html("tarefa okay");   
    $("#menu").after('<li><a id="'+id+'" onClick="return adicionaItem('+id+');">Menu '+id+'</a></li>'); 
    id++;       
}

function adicionaItemNoMenu()
{   
    /*
    (1)Cria Novo Objeto Item do Menu na lista da de objetos itens do menu, 
    em seguida atualiza o menu
    */
    var instanciaItemMenu=new itemMenu(id,'hi');
    menuPrincipal.push(new itemMenu(id,'Menu '+id));
    this.id=id+1;   
    atualizaMenuControlador();
}

function atualizaMenuControlador()
{   
    /*
    (2)Insere as atualizações processadas pela função atualiza 
    menu enviando o array de objetos de menu
    */
    $("#menu").html(atualizaMenuComClasse(menuPrincipal,"botaoMenu"));  
}


function atualizaMenu(arrayDeListas)
{
    return atualizaMenuComClasse(arrayDeListas,""); 
}


function atualizaMenuComClasse(arrayDeListas,classe)
{   
    /*
    (2.1) Processa objetos do array de objetos de menu (botões do menu) retornando-os em forma
    de Html para serem inseridos no menu.
    */
    var textoFinalDoMenu="";
    if(classe.length==0)
    textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+'<ul>';    
    else
        textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+'<ul>';

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < arrayDeListas.length ; i++ ) {
        textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+'<li class='+classe+' id='+arrayDeListas[i].idItem+'>';
        textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+arrayDeListas[i].descricao;
        if(arrayDeListas[i].itensMenuInterno>0){
            textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+atualizaMenu(arrayDeListas);          
        }
        textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+'</li>';      
    }   
    textoFinalDoMenu=textoFinalDoMenu+'</ul>';
    return textoFinalDoMenu;
}


</script>

</head>
<body>




<table>
<tr>
<td id="menu"></td>
<td id="botao">
<form>
<button value="Adiciona" onclick="adicionaItemNoMenu();return false;">Adiciona1</button>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(function (){` is the equiv of `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: It is working Check [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9agvv/). Do you get any error on console where you are  testing it ?

Comment: I do not use console, there is an IDE to javascript? I programming it in a JSP page in Eclipse. Look: this <li id="1" class="botaoMenu">Menu 1</li> is an generated Jquery code (I am using firebug to see the generated HTML code) , can it be the source of problem, does this function does not work with the non existing primary code?